# Foundation 5 Horizontal tabs not displaying properly missing css

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

i am using foundation 5 and copied the html code for the horizontal tab

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
  <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
    <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
    <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

now the css is not being applied to the sample code.
Please help me where can i find the css.

thanks.

Comment: css not being applied?? foundation comes with default css files.did you add the stylesheet?

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer its not him the foundation 5 css has a `dl.tabs` it used to be `ul.tabs` before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded the essentials package. you should try to download the complete one as the essentials don't have css applied.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation 5 tabs have been switched from `ul` to `dl` below is the structure the want

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
   <dd class="active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></dd>
  ....
```

[link on git](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/cc02ba23bed58145c0273955262b2738b7a82d29/doc/includes/tabs/examples_tabs_basic.html)

the docs are outdated

Answer (score 0):

nolawi petros' answer is the correct one: they changed the syntax without updating the documentation.

Here is the full syntax (same as the one nolavi linked to, just a bit shorter):

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the plus side, they fixed deep-linking to an individual tab so the documentation is now correct regarding this. If you want to use deep linking you should include "data-options="deep_linking:true" in the first line, like so:

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab data-options="deep_linking:true">
```

Note that you'll have to call foundation.tab.js for deep linking to work; otherwise tabs seems to work out of the box.